# Assuredly simple C# file saving issue

Tags: c#, web

We have a custom built web application built on ASP (2.0 it looks like) using C#.  We recently moved it from an IIS6 environment to an IIS7.  We have run into an issue where a page set up to view images that had been retrieved via a search is throwing an error.  The code takes a copy of the image file and puts it into a work directory renaming the copy to the user's name.

```
bmpList[0].Save("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SiteName\\Work\\" + ((ImageUser)Session["ImageUser"]).Username + ".TIF", info, encParams);
```

I know that the wwwroot is no longer a valid directory in the path so I changed it to...

```
bmpList[0].Save("c:\\inetpub\\SiteName\\Work\\" + ((ImageUser)Session["ImageUser"]).Username + ".TIF", info, encParams);
```

Saved the file, did and IIS restart and cleared my browser cache and still receive an error...

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Source Error: 
Line 180:                       
Line 181:                    //bmpList[0].Save("c:\\pi\\" + ((ImageUser)Session["ImageUser"]).Username + ".TIF", info, encParams);
Line 182:                    bmpList[0].Save("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SiteName\\Work\\" + ((ImageUser)Session["ImageUser"]).Username + ".TIF", info, encParams);
Line 183:
Line 184:                    for (int a = 1; a < numFiles; a++)


Source File: c:\inetpub\Sitename\SiteApp\View.aspx.cs    Line: 182 

Stack Trace: 
[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +615209
View.Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\SiteName\SiteApp\View.aspx.cs:182
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +11056766
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

It seems like a fairly straightforward thing but for some reason it is not updating (the path in the error remains exactly the same).  What am I missing?

Comment: Is your browser caching something?

Comment: How are you loading the image? It could still have an open file handle and therefore isn't allowing you to save

Comment: Can you show the error with the bad path? The one in your post is only showing the source location which matches your specification.

Comment: `0x80004005` smells like `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, even with the presence of `FACILITY_ITF`.

Comment: 1) I have cleared my cache, tried a different browser and another machine, same results.

Comment: 2)I did not write this nor am I even passably literate in C.  I can say that the error that is presenting keeps showing up with the old path showing in the code's source error.  Which brings me to...

Comment: 3)  Updated the error on the original question.

Comment: I went so far as to remove the view.aspx.cs (source code) file and I still receive the error.   Is this perhaps a function of ASP.Net pre-compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So oddly enough the answer is actually as simple as it looks... almost. 
Changing...
    c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteName\Work\
to...
     c:\inetpub\SiteName\Work\
worked.  Why it was continuing to give me the same error from the browser after I changed the code on the .cs file was that the IP that they had bound to the site still belonged to a previous version of the machine so DNS was routing me over to that box instead.  All said it ended up I was on the wrong OSI model layer.  I only discovered it when I went to build a test version on the same box and went to unbind the IP from the broken site and bind it to my second test site and I found that the IP I wanted wasn't an option (so it must have been manually entered).  Live and learn.  Thanks for the input and advise.

Comment: You really should not be using those paths at all, instead just use [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath(@"~/Work/")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will point at the same location and you don't need to hardcode the path on the hard drive.

Comment: I didn't write this app I was just migrating it across servers but your advise is perfect and I will implement it.  I'm not familiar with C (haven't done anything with it since a C++ college course almost 2 decades ago) but relative pathing is absolutely more correct.  I used to the $_ convention from powershell. :P

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the time (i.e 99.9999% of the times), when using GDI, 'a generic error occured' means that the directory you are trying to save to doesn't have the proper permissions. Typically, you need to make sure that directory is allowing asp.net to modify files. Did you check the permission on the directory you are trying to save the files to?

Comment: I think so, before you save use the `Directory.Exists` Method to see if the path is valid.

Comment: I believe that the issue is that the directory the page is trying to load does not exist.  I have changed the code but it is not updating to the changed path as I receive the same path on the error page.

Comment: Is there any config file that points to the directory that doesn't exist? Can you debug the code and see if it is using a path that might come from a config file?